# When the equation $y = ax + n$ is perpendicular to $x$ axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this statement:

Determine what should happen in the equation $ax + n = y$ to be:

$i) \perp$ to $y-$axis

$ii) \perp$ to $x-$axis

My attempt was:

For $i)$, when the equation is $\perp$ to $y-$axis, mean that the slope is equal to zero. Therefore, if i want $ax+n=y$ be $\perp$ to $y-$axis, $a$ must be $0$ and we have $y=n$, with $n$ a constant.

For $ii)$, when the equation is $\perp$ to $x-$axis, mean that the slope is $\infty$, but i don't know how to express this algebraically. Also i know that a equation perpendicular to $x-$axis is of the form $x=k$ with $k$ a constant, but i don't know how to get $x=k$ from $ax+n=y$ as i did in $i)$

My second attempt for $ii)$ was:

Since $y = ax+n \to x = \frac{y-n}{x}$ and $\frac{y-n}{a}$ must be a constant and since in $\frac{y-n}{a}$ the unique element that isn't constant is $y$, then $y$ must be $0$ to get $x = -\frac{n}{a}$. Is this the correct solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes,  your solution for part $i$ and your second attempt for part $ii$ are correct.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad

Comment: But "y must be $0$" doesn't produce a *line*...

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 why not ?

Comment: The points on the line are ordered pairs of the form $(x, y)$. Setting $y = 0$ just gives us ONE point, namely $(-n/a, y)$

Comment: Instead, we want an equation of the form $x = c$, for some constant *c*, to have a vertical line. Likewise, we want an equation of the form $y = c$ for a horizontal line. Why they didn't just use the standard form of an equation $ax + by = c$ is beyond me!

Comment: So, what is the solution according to you?

Comment: "y should not be present" ?? Honestly, I don't see the question as being particularly well-posed. When you say, in your second attempt at (ii), that the fraction must be constant, there should be an acknowledgment that a variable expression (containing y) cannot be constant.

Comment: I mean that the fraction must be constant since when i want a line $\perp$ to $x-$axis the equation is of the form $x = k$ with $k$ a constant, and since $x = \frac{y-n}{a}$ the fraction is equal to the constant

Comment: Yes, but the fraction contains a variable (x and y are variables; a,c,k,n are constants).

Comment: I think you have the idea (since you said "the equation is of the form $x = k$"), but how to best answer the question is not clear.

Comment: basically the question is, what should happen to the other participants in the equation, i.e in the equation $y = ax +n$ what should happen with $y, a, n$ to get $x = k$ as i did in $i)$